# What is ?v=something mean in a JavaScript file name?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've noticed on many sites the JavaScript file has it's regular name then `?v=something` The something can be alphanumeric, or just random numbers.

For example:

```
<script src="./bundle.js?v=21knfa"></scrip>
```

I have a few questions about this:

## The purpose:

What is the purpose of adding `?v=something` on the file name. For example, does it allow the developers to have multiple versions of their code?

## Server or Client

Is this done by the server or the client?

## How would this be done

How would you add the version automatically to your JavaScript filename, does it involve a software like Docker to do this? Or is this done in another way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you add something, the URL changes and is not cached in the browser and forced to be loaded.

Comment: It's a cachebuster, if you change the get parameters, the browser will fetch a new file instead of using it's cache

Comment: So there aren't multiple files with the same name but different `?v=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Purpose

It is for client-side caching.

If you have a JS file script.js, the users browser will cache it.  When you change script.js, the browser will still have the old cached version.

So, you add a `?v=...` to it so when you make changes, the browser will load the new one.

Since it is in the HTML file, it is the server that sets the `?v=...`

To do this yourself, simply add the `?v=...`

```
<script src="javascript.js?v=1.0.1" type="text/javascipt"></script>
```

### Example

Say you make a script for your site and name it "script.js".

In your code you put:

```
<script src="script.js?v=1" type="text/javascipt"></script>
```

Now when you change "script.js", you change your code as follows:

```
<script src="script.js?v=2" type="text/javascipt"></script>
```

Now your visitor's browsers will get the new "version" of your script file.

### Also

You could use `?foo=...` or really any other string.

Comment: Could you provide an example programmatically